# unique user name but duplicate password

Tags: users

I'm having a developer work on a site for me.  I'm being told that each user must have a unique username.  That makes sense.  I'm also told that they all need to have a unique password.  This doesn't make sense and is causing problems for me client.
Shouldn't a unique combination of username and password be what's required?
Can anyone help direct me to a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) You've mentioned you're looking for a solution but I'm not sure I understand what problem you're looking to solve? Are you looking for literature on whether passwords should be unique? Are you looking for help to undo what your developer has implemented re passwords? If you could edit the question just to clarify that would be great. Please bear in mind that requests for links are off-topic here, and this isn't the right place to get into a discussion about whether passwords should be unique...

Comment: ... There is an [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/), I'm sure a question about whether unique passwords provides any real protection would be welcomed there (if that's what you're asking)

Comment: What I'm asking (and I apologize if this is not the right place to ask) is whether or not it's a requirement within Drupal for a user to have BOTH a unique username and password.  I would think that two users with two different usernames could have the same password.  Just trying to find out if that is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, seems like what you need to know fits into the site just fine. Your assumption that Drupal doesn't enforce unique passwords is correct. It could likely be made to do so, but out of the box there's a very limited password policy

Answer (score 2):

Users can have the same password, but they cannot have the same username by default. Theoretically, users could have the same username with some customization, but they would need to log in with something else that makes them unique such as an e-mail address.